# How do I actually disable Wi-Fi or Bluetooth in iOS 11 Control Center?

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, ios, control-center

In iOS 11, I can't disable Bluetooth or Wi-Fi using the redesigned Control Center. It disconnects from any Bluetooth/Wi-Fi devices but the radios are still on, draining battery. It also doesn't disable AirDrop either. If I disable Bluetooth or Wi-Fi using settings this shows:

[image]
[image]

How can I quickly disable Bluetooth/Wi-Fi without having to go to settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using a launcher app to automate this step. I know that Apple put in some restrictions on launching these, but there's [one claiming to allow "easy access to settings"](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/shortcuts-easy-access-to-settings/id1257401755?mt=8) and it works on my iPhone.

The top two lines give you access to Wi-Fi and Bluetooth. You could add them to the Notification Centre.

[image: Shortcuts screen shot]
[image: Notification Centre]

Answer (score 4):

As @mikeScott already answered in the comment, you can’t do it with control center.

You have to

- go to settings > Wi-Fi or
- use Siri (turn off Wi-Fi)

Comment: Apple apparently does that so that your phone won't accidentally lose contact for things like Handoff or lose connectivity to your Apple Watch. It's annoying, but you could use a launcher app for quick access. Not perfect and not intuitive but might be worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 11, Apple makes Wi-Fi and Bluetooth always on to keep certain features intact, like AirDrop. There is no choice but to turn them off in Settings app. Kind of time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 17.2.1 you can use the native [Shortcuts app](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios):

- open Shortcuts
- switch to **Automation** tab
- create a new automation by pressing the **+** sign in the top right corner
- scroll down and choose **Wi-Fi** or **Bluetooth**
- Under **Network**, **Choose** which you want to automate (I chose **Any Network**) and confirm with **Done**
- toggle **Network Left** and choose **Run Immediately**
- press on **New Blank Automation** button
- type **Set Wi-Fi** or **Set Bluetooth** into the search bar
- **Turn** Wi-Fi **Off**
- Finish by pressing **Done** it the top right corner

Unfortunately, this only works if your device was connected to another device and not if you switch **Wi-Fi**/**Bluetooth** on and off again immediately.